# In javascript convert numbers to a date format yyyymmdd to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, date

I am taking an XML feed and writing it to HTML using JavaScript.

The date field has:

`20120319`

What I want to do is convert it to a more readable format like:

`03/19/2012`

Is there an easy way of doing this in JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.  I ended up using this code: `exp.replace(/(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)/g, '$2/$3/$1');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to write:

```
s = s.replace(/(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/g, '$2/$3/$1');
```

which uses a regular expression to [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) a sequence of four digits, followed by a sequence of two digits, followed by a sequence of two digits, with the second, plus a `/`, plus the third, plus a `/`, plus the first.

Comment: `(\d\d\d\d)` isn't beautiful - better is `(\d{4})`

Comment: @Neysor: If the OP had mentioned regexes, then I would have supplied `\d{4}`, but as it was, I wasn't sure if (s)he was at *all* familiar with regexes, so I figured it was best to use as simple a syntax as possible.

Answer (score 7):

Ideally, you should use a locale insensitive date format like "2012-03-19" which is unambiguous worldwide.  That said:

```
var dateStr = "20120319";
var match = dateStr.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/);
var betterDateStr = match[2] + '/' + match[3] + '/' + match[1];
```

will do what you want.  This hardcodes MDY.  If you want DMY, as used in most of Europe, then swap `match[2]` and `match[3]`.

If you want a heuristic to detect whether the current locale prefers the month or day first, then

```
(new Date('01/02/1970').getDate() === 2)
```

can help.

Comment: +1 Not just "as used in most of Europe", but in most of the world. Oh, and don't trust Date to parse strings, it will fail when you lease expect it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to write

```
var s = String("20181011"); s = s.slice(4,6)+"/"+s.slice(6,8)+"/"+s.slice(0,4)
```

which uses the String object only.