# How to add google analytics data into a 2D array in app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get the date from google analytics as 2017-05-23. But I'm getting the date as 20170523. code is as follows,Can any one amend this code to get the date as above.

```
function getReportDataForProfile1(firstProfile) {

  var profileId = firstProfile.getId();
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;
  var startDate = getLastNdays(7);   // 2 weeks (a fortnight) ago.
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);      // Today.

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:dayOfWeekName,ga:userType',              // Comma separated list of dimensions.
    //'sort': 'ga:pageviews',       // Sort by sessions descending, then keyword.
    //'segment': 'dynamic::ga:isMobile==Yes',  // Process only mobile traffic.
    'filters': 'ga:pagePath=~oho;ga:pagePath=~\\?;ga:pagePath=~accommodation',          // Display only google traffic.
    'start-index': '1',
    //'max-results': '50'                     // Display the first 250 results.
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
      tableId,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
    'ga:pageviews,ga:sessions,ga:sessionDuration,ga:users,ga:bounces,ga:bounceRate,ga:hits', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
      optArgs);

  if (results.getRows()) {
    return results;

  } else {
    throw new Error('No views (profiles) found');
  }
}
```

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question and your code doesn't relate to the question either. Is your question about the date formatting or extracting the data into String[][]?

Comment: I am also not understanding how your code relates to your question. Since you know the format of your date, you can just use the substring method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: My question is  the date comes as a number (ex;20170423) not as a date  In var optArgs function ga:date when taken into spread sheet. So how can I convert just a number to a date format..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript method [match](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) to convert that number to a dateformat like:

```
var dateStr = "20170523";
var match = dateStr.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/);
var betterDateStr = match[2] + '/' + match[3] + '/' + match[1];
alert(dateStr);
```

will output: `05/23/2017`

Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795991/in-javascript-convert-numbers-to-a-date-format-yyyymmdd-to-mm-dd-yyyy) for more info.